# Can we use Spring MVC Framework and other components of Spring framework (like AOP) together?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am new to Spring. Just having basic understanding of it.

I am curious to know, can we use `Spring MVC Framework` and other components of Spring framework (like `AOP`) together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly yes.
quote

Spring could potentially be a one-stop shop for all your enterprise applications, however, Spring is modular, allowing you to pick and choose which modules are applicable to you, without having to bring in the rest. You can read details about modules available in Spring Framework.[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_architecture.htm)